# Get nth word in a string delimited by "."

Tags: sql, sql-server

Already have the query to get the first word delimited by ".", I need a new column that displays the 3rd word

```
SELECT   
    MyColumn, 
    LEFT(MyColumn, CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn) - 1) AS [1st Sequence]
FROM    
    dbo.MyTable
```

Sample #1:

```
2345.Z2Z2.A12151.AB4R
```

Query should return `A12151`

Sample #2:

```
STR4.35S982F.X24
```

Query should return `X24`

EDIT:

Thanks everyone for sharing your queries. Although the WITH CTE worked, I'm thinking of a simplier query since this will be used as a datasource to my dropdownlist and will always refresh when another dropdownlist changes.

I think this can be done by SUBSTRING. Please see below a query I've found and tested which extracts the 2nd word. I'm currently modifying this to extract the 3rd word. If anyone could help me with this, I would be very greatful:

```
SELECT MyColumn,
SUBSTRING(MyColumn, CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn) + 1 , CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn, CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn)+1) - (CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn) + 1))
FROM dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: Probably not the easiest way, but do something similar to `LEFT(..., RIGHT(..., CI('.', RIGHT(...))-1)-1)`

Comment: SQL Server 2016 introduced `STRING_SPLIT`. Which version are you targeting? In any case there are a *lot* of duplicate questions that show how to split a string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Good advice!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the implementation of `STRING_SPLIT` is deficient though as it doesn't include an index column - so there is no guaranteed way of getting the nth item.

Comment: @MartinSmith no, it's not deficient, it's actually [faster than any other string splitting technique](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split), it returns a table not individual values and so it *can* be used with ROW_NUMBER() to return individual items.

Comment: But there is no guarantee that `row_number() over (order by some_constant_expression)` will number the rows numbered in the order returned by the function. It probably will. This isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @MartinSmith you can use a SQLCLR method. If you check the SQLCLR split implementations though you'll agree it's a bit more involved thatn calling `String.Split`. All of the earlier string splitting techniques though will end up being slower and harder to maintain

Comment: My comments are nothing to do with efficiency. The defficiency I was pointing out was the lack of an index/position column.

Comment: @MartinSmith that's not a deficiency. No string splitting method returns an index because that's not their job. SQL works with sets of records, not rows. That doesn't mean they are deficient. The best solution would be a function that *didn't* split at all, one that found the N-1th and Nth delimiter indexes and returned the string between them.

Comment: If you want this for a dropdown, why not split on the *client*? If you want to use data binding map the values to an object and bind to its properties. SQL is *not* the proper language for such things.

Comment: I'm trying to handle all the data retrieval in my Data Access Layer. It would be better if my SP can output the needed values instead of applying the logic in UI level

Comment: @HarambeAttackHelicopter the data access layer is your client code that handles data access and/or your ORM. What you try to do here leaks *UI* concerns into the database.  Converting database data to objects that can be handled by the UI is the job of the data access code on the client, not the SQL code.

Comment: @HarambeAttackHelicopter in fact, the leak has already happened - a field should only contain one value. When you ask about the Nth value it means that you needed at least N more columns in your table to hold extra properties. You can't create such values in SQL (at least not before 2017) which means the *client* stored them there. It's the client's job to deserialize that data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos some string splitting functions do return the item's position. :) In fact, in my view, a **good** string splitting function (in SQL Server) should return the ordinal position; as the order of data (as we all know) is never guaranteed without an `ORDER BY`. The possibility of having a delimited list returned in a different order to what it was passed could be a huge problem; especially when you have no way of reconstructing that order due to the lack of ordinal position information.

Comment: @Larnu - It is in the backlog apparently https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32896627-string-split-add-option-to-return-row-number

Comment: @MartinSmith "apparently" indeed. The comment from Microsoft was made in April 2017. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS RowNo, LEFT(MyColumn, CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn)-1) AS Word,
    RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn)) AS Remainder
  FROM Dummy
  WHERE CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn) >0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT RowNo +1, LEFT(Remainder, CHARINDEX('.', Remainder)-1) AS Word,
    RIGHT(Remainder, LEN(Remainder) - CHARINDEX('.', Remainder)) AS Remainder
  FROM CTE
  WHERE CHARINDEX('.', Remainder) >0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT RowNo+ 1, Remainder As Word, NULL As Remainder
  FROM CTE
  WHERE CHARINDEX('.', Remainder) = 0
)
SELECT Word
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNo = 3
```

Result:

> X24
>
> A12151

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6274e/1)

For further details, please see: [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186243(v=sql.105))

[EDIT#2]

Assuming that you want to get every single word into different column, you have to change last `SELECT` statement to:

```
SELECT ID, [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM (
  SELECT RowNo, Word, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RowNo ORDER BY RowNo) AS ID
  FROM CTE
) AS src
PIVOT (MAX(Word) FOR RowNo IN([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS pvt
```

Result:

```
ID  1       2           3       4

1   2345    35S982F     A12151  AB4R

2   STR4    Z2Z2        X24     (null)
```

Comment: You don't need `RowIndex+1`, SQL Server has ROW_NUMBER and other ranking functions in all supported versions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, i know. I only wanted to show how to refer to the nth word. It's also showing how CTE work.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to split strings anyway and many duplicate questions. All of them describe one of the techniques described by Aaron Bertrand [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) and [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split). This answer uses substrings instead of indexes thus using a lot more memory. The CTE solution in Bertrand's articles uses indexes only and ends up being one of the fastest techniques

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, good to know. Thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: How do I edit this and add the 1st word as a column? I'm still trying to understand how the with cte works :)

Comment: @HarambeAttackHelicopter, You mean, you want to get every single word into different column?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Already added this column to all 3 select statements: `LEFT(MyColumn, CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn) - 1) `

Answer (score 8):

First, a quick and dirty solution that works in SQL Server 2016 and later is to convert the string to a JSON array by replacing the delimiter with `","` and use [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to extract only the Nth value :

```
select JSON_VALUE('["' + REPLACE('2345.Z2Z2.A12151.AB4R','.','","') + '"]','$[2]')
```

This returns

```
A12151
```

This is dirty because it performs a (possibly heavy) string replacement. This can add up if the function is applied to a lot of rows.

A better solution though would be to *not* split the string in SQL. The question says

> this will be used as a datasource to my dropdownlist and will always refresh when another dropdownlist changes

Parsing for display purposes is the job of the client's data access code, not the database's. In the first place, a field should only contain a *single* value. If the four values in `2345.Z2Z2.A12151.AB4R` are significant they should be stored in 4 different fields, allowing easy querying and indexing.

That said, there *are* cases where one would want to store [Value Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects) - data items with values that shouldn't be treated as separate entites. Many ORMs offer support for Value Objects, like EF Core 2.0 and NHibernate.

With a value object, the four values in the string can be mapped into individual properties and used in databinding expressions in the UI. Implementing a Value object is easy, even without ORM support. It could be as easy as creating a class with a constructor that accepts a string and a `ToString()` override that returns the string to serialize, eg :

```
class MyComplexInvoice
{
    public string A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
    public string C {get;set;}
    public string D {get;set;}

    public MyComplexInvoice(string input)
    {
      var items=inmput.Split('.');
      A=items[0];
      ...
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{A}.{B}.{C}.{D}";
    }        

}
```

A better implementation would use `Parse()` and `TryParse()` methods like those found on most built-in types, eg :

```
class MyComplexInvoice
{
    public string A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
    public string C {get;set;}
    public string D {get;set;}

    public MyComplexInvoice(string a,string string c,string d)
    {
      A=a ?? throw ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
      ...
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string input,out MyComplexInvoice inv)
    {
        inv=null;
        if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(input) return false;

        var items=inmput.Split('.');

        if (items.Length!=4) return false;
        // More validations ....

        inv=new MyComplexInvoice(items[0],items[1],items[2],items[3]);

        return true;            
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{A}.{B}.{C}.{D}";
    }        

}
```

Comment: The solution with JSON_VALUE, its superb. Thanks !

Comment: But for very small strings which need to be split only once in a procedure this looks perfect.

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to use Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). The advantage of this splitter is it returns the **ordinal position** of each item, which is vital for your goal. it's also something many others don't return (including SQL Server's `STRING_SPLIT`). This then becomes very simple:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('2345.Z2Z2.A12151.AB4R'),('STR4.35S982F.X24'))V(S))    
SELECT DS.Item
FROM VTE
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(VTE.S,'.') DS
WHERE DS.ItemNumber = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a work around by using the [`PARSENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but the limitation it will not support, if you have more than three dots in the string.

Query execution using sample data:

```
DECLARE @SampleTable TABLE (TextValue VARCHAR (2000));

INSERT INTO @SampleTable (TextValue)
VALUES ('2345.Z2Z2.A12151.AB4R'), ('STR4.35S982F.X24'), ('123.345'), ('12345'), (NULL);

SELECT  CASE (LEN(TextValue) - LEN(REPLACE(TextValue, '.', '')))
        WHEN 3 THEN PARSENAME(TextValue, 2)
        WHEN 2 THEN PARSENAME(TextValue, 1)
        ELSE TextValue
        END AS TextValue
FROM @SampleTable
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create your own function for it, pretty much the logic can be like this.

This function I created and modified so we can get any delimited character from any position of sequence and any character of delimiter or character to split each text, so it's kind of multifunction of splitting character.

So this can be very useful in any ocassion of splitting character of text anytime when you need it

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TextSplit ( @input VARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter VARCHAR, @charPosition INT)
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @textsearch NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT
 DECLARE @ loop INT

SET @loop = 1

 WHILE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input) > 0
 BEGIN

  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @input)  

  SELECT @textsearch = SUBSTRING(@input, 1, @pos-1)

  SELECT @input = SUBSTRING(@input, @pos+1, LEN(@input)-@pos)

  IF @loop = @charPosition
      SET @result = @textsearch;

  SET @loop = @loop + 1
 END

 RETURN(@result);
END
```

In order to execute it, you can do it like

```
SELECT   MyColumn
        ,LEFT(MyColumn, CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn) - 1) AS [1st Sequence]
       ,TextSplit(MyColumn, '.', 3) as thirdsequence
FROM    dbo.MyTable
```

So you can get any delimited character from any position of sequence and any character of delimiter, so it's kind of multifunction of splitting character

Comment: Formatted that SQL for you. :)

Comment: 1) this is the slowest way possible to split a string. 2) There's no need to split here, just find the Nth value. To do that you need to search for the delimiter N-1 times and only retrieve the substring between that match and the next delimiter. The improvement can be *huge* when you apply the function to a lot of rows and queries

Comment: Thank you @Larnu :)

Comment: @Kanavos, I noticed that the query need to be optimized for better performance,  depending on the needs, but the query is basically dynamically searching and splitting all characters in every each X delimiter (you customize what is the delimiter), and return N character of the expected values to be returned (for example 1st character before 1st position of delimiter, or first character after 1st position of delimiter)

Answer (score 1):

In T-SQL you could use a window function:

```
declare @nthPos int = 2

select MyColumn, 
    (
        select [value] 
        from (
            select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as 'ID', [value] 
            from string_split(MyColumn, '.')
        ) x 
        where ID = @nthPos
    ) as 'nthValue'
from dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have SQL2016 and you are not allowed to create functions or stored procedures you can cast to xml and then select the nth node.

```
declare @someText nvarchar(max) = 'this is some very interesting text'

select CAST( '<p>'+Replace(rtrim(ltrim(@someText)),' ','</p><p>')+'</p>' AS XML).value('(/p)[5]','nvarchar(MAX)')

result -> interesting
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this-

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('2345.Z2Z2.A12151.AB4R'),('STR4.35S982F.X24'))V(S)
)
,CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT * , 
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(S),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(S),0)
    ,(CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(S), CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(S),0)+1) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(S),0)))) N FROM CTE   
)
SELECT S,SUBSTRING(N,0,LEN(N)) N
FROM CTE1
```

OUTPUT

```
S                     N
--------------------- ---------------------
2345.Z2Z2.A12151.AB4R A12151
STR4.35S982F.X24      35S982F

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: How do I convert `SELECT * FROM (VALUES('2345.Z2Z2.A12151.AB4R'),('STR4.35S982F.X24'))V(S)` to MyTable?

Comment: ;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT * , 
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(S),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(S),0)
    ,(CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(S), CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(S),0)+1) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(S),0)))) N FROM MyTable   
)
SELECT S,SUBSTRING(N,0,LEN(N)) N
FROM CTE1

Answer (score 0):

I've needed this exact thing, for a pesky log file, that has data needing parsing. I wrote two versions. One with a Tally table and the other without. From what I read, the Tally table version should be faster.  Not sure if that's true or not but here is what I ended up with. I must admit much of the code below, for the Tally table, is from another post. If I find it I will reference it.

(SQL SERVER)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_SplitGetNth (@pSTR VARCHAR(MAX),@pOccurance int,@pDlm VARCHAR(MAX)=',')
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @vRslt VARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @pSTR=@pDlm + @pSTR + @pDlm;
 SELECT @vrslt=Word FROM
    (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@pstr,id+1,CHARINDEX(@pDlm,@pSTR,id+1)-id-1)[Word],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)[Position]
    FROM Tally where id<LEN(@pstr)
    AND SUBSTRING(@pSTR,ID,1)=@pDlm 
    ) a
    WHERE a.Position=@pOccurance

  RETURN @vRslt;
end

Usage:
SELECT dbo.fn_SplitGetNth('STR4.35S982F.X24',3,'.')
```

Result:

```
COLUMN1
-------
X24
```

Without a Tally Table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplitStringX
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1),
    @nthValue int
) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(120) 
 AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT, @cnt INT=0;

    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1
        SET @cnt=@cnt+1
        -- INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        IF (@cnt=@nthValue)
        BEGIN
              RETURN SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start) 
        END
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
        
    END 
    RETURN ''
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION TextSplit (@Testo VARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter VARCHAR(128), @Position INT)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

        DECLARE @Xml XML
        DECLARE @Output TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),SplitData varchar(max))
        DECLARE @Result varchar(max)

        SET @Xml = CAST(('<a>'+REPLACE(@Testo,@delimiter,'</a><a>')+'</a>') AS XML)

        INSERT INTO @Output (SplitData)
        SELECT ltrim(rtrim(A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')))  FROM @Xml.nodes('a') AS FN(a)
        SET @Result = (SELECT SplitData FROM @Output WHERE ID = @Position)

    RETURN(@Result);
END
```